# Should I use Enum, static Class, Dictionary or Struct to represent these "labeled floats" in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, structure

I have a constant data structure that represents the relative height of each human vertebra, normalized in relation to total spine height. This is derived from anthropometric studies, etc.

I have implemented it in Python as a tuple of tuples, each tuple containing a (string)Name and (double)Value, like this:

```
vertebral_heights = (
("C7",  0.0000000),
("T1",  0.0391914),
("T2",  0.0785479),
("T3",  0.1183993),
("T4",  0.1590759),
("T5",  0.2009076),
("T6",  0.2442244),
("T7",  0.2893564),
("T8",  0.3366337),
("T9",  0.3863861),
("T10", 0.4389439),
("T11", 0.4946370),
("T12", 0.5537954),
("L1",  0.6167492),
("L2",  0.6838284),
("L3",  0.7553630),
("L4",  0.8316832),
("L5",  0.9131188),
("S1",  1.0000000))
```

My first thought was to create a Dictionary, but that would need a class to be used as a container. Then the idea of an Enum came to mind, but I have read "enums are for ints", and I have doubles. Then there are Class and Struct, but to this point I am utterly confused, and I believe my current understanding of the best practices of doing this stuff in C# is not enough, yet.

My intended use is to have a "map" between the application model (the numeric part of the elements) and the user model (the named, domain-related part of the elements).

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you need to access them dynamically (via the label name) then a Dictionary is probably best. If you are only referencing them by variable name then a bunch of constants in a single class is probably fine (given there isn't really that many)

Comment: @musefan 1) they would be static/constant/readonly; 2) I would like to preserve some "relative order" between them, in an `IEnumerable` sense; Getting the values via `vertebral_heights.L3`, for example, would be nice.

Comment: For a collection that small, List<> could be faster than a dictionary. Benchmark it, if performance is important..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to access the values.

**Constants**

If you will always use variable names, for example:

```
double x = C7;
```

then you can just use a class full of constants like so:

```
public class VertebralHeights
{
    public const double C7 = 0.0000000d;
}
```

**Dictionary**

However, if you want to access them dynamically, for example:

```
string id = "C7";
double x = VertebralHeights[id];
```

then you will be better off with a `Dictionary` which you can define like so:

```
Dictionary<string, double> VertebralHeights = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    { "C7", 0.0000000d },
    { "T1", 0.0391914d}
}
```

---

**Having both ways together**.

If you want both strongly-typed and dynamic access to the value you can extend either of the above methods...

For **constants** (method 1) add a function that takes a string:

```
public double GetValue(string s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
        case "C7": return C7;
        case "T7": return T7;
        //...and so on...
        default: return 0;//or an alternate default
    }
}
```

(note: you could do this with reflection instead, which would be easier with a massive list, but isn't really worth the extra performance hit here)

For the **Dictionary** approach (method 2), you could add a collection of getters:

```
public double C7 { get { return VertebralHeights["C7"]; } }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my take on this - work with a singleton class which is a Dictionary:

```
public class Vertebrae : Dictionary<string, double>
{
    private Vertebrae() : base() { }


    private static Vertebrae _heights = new Vertebrae() {
        { "C7", 0.0 },
        { "T1", 0.0391914 },
        { "T2", 0.0785479 },
    };

    public static Vertebrae Heights { get { return _heights; } }

    public static double C7 { get { return Heights["C7"]; } }
    public static double T1 { get { return Heights["T1"]; } }
    public static double T2 { get { return Heights["T2"]; } }

    public static IEnumerable<double> All
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<double>() { C7, T1, T2 };
        }
    }
}
```

To access your Vertebrae by string name, you do:

```
double c7 = Vertebrae.Heights["C7"];
```

To access your Vertebrae by symbolic name, you do:

```
double c7 = Vertebrae.C7;
```

To enumerate your Vertebrae you do:

```
foreach (double v in Vertebrae.All) { /* ... */ }
```

For the enumerator you could have a single static List initialized as in the enumerator, but I wasn't sure which would get initialized first, the static list or the static dictionary...

Comment: I see that you're trying to make the class a static dictionary, but doesn't this make  `Vertebrae.Heights.Heights.Heights` valid?  It might be better to encapsulate the dictionary instead of inherit from it.  You've already had to write encapsulating functions for _heights since you're not using the native dictionary storage anywhere.  Shame a static class can't implement an interface though...

Comment: I think if I was going as far as 
    `public static double C7 { get { return Heights["C7"]; } }` I'd just make C7 a constant string `public static string C7 = "C7"` and the user could use `Vertebrae.Heights[Vertebrae.C7]`

Comment: No - you can only reference a static member from a class, not from an instance of the class so `Vertebrae.Heights.Heights` is illegal.

Answer (score 6):

Do it as an enum, and write the black-box plumbing code up front. You will not regret it! Here's what I would do:

Write a custom attribute so that you can associate the double value to each enum:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class VertebralHeightAsDoubleAttribute : Attribute
{
  public double HeightValue { get; private set; }

  public VertebralHeightAsDoubleAttribute(double heightValue_)
  {
    HeightValue = heightValue_;
  }
}
```

Some extension methods to make life easier:

```
public static class VHAttribExtensions
{
  public static string ToNameString(this VertebralHeight target)
  {
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(VertebralHeight), target);
  }

  public static double ToHeightValue(this VertebralHeight target)
  {
    var fi = target.GetType().GetField(target.ToString());
    var attributes = (VertebralHeightAsDoubleAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
      typeof(VertebralHeightAsDoubleAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].HeightValue : double.NaN;
  }
}
```

Define your enum using the custom attribute:

```
public enum VertebralHeight
{
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.0000000)]
  C7,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.0391914)]
  T1,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.0785479)]
  T2,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.1183993)]
  T3,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.1590759)]
  T4,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.2009076)]
  T5,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.2442244)]
  T6,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.2893564)]
  T7,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.3366337)]
  T8,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.3863861)]
  T9,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.4389439)]
  T10,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.4946370)]
  T11,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.5537954)]
  T12,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.6167492)]
  L1,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.6838284)]
  L2,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.7553630)]
  L3,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.8316832)]
  L4,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(0.9131188)]
  L5,
  [VertebralHeightAsDouble(1.0000000)]
  S1
}
```

Test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VertebralHeight)).OfType<VertebralHeight>();
  foreach (var vh in list)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", vh.ToNameString(), vh.ToHeightValue());
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting, and very "advanced", too. Even though, when I look at my naive Python implementation, it "feels" it deserved (and most probably could have) a way leaner implementation... Some sorts of the C# verbosity just don't feel right to me, yet... :oP

Comment: Yeah, this approach pretty much eliminates the need to write any special `switch` statements. Also eliminates a lot of code duplication. Adding any new enum members is pretty facile too (although I doubt the human body can develop any new vertebral bones in the near future, lol).

Comment: @heltonbiker this is a quite clean approach, what do you mean by the verbosity? You can name the attribute any way you want, even just `H` if that's what you're at, the same goes for `ToNameString()` (`Name()`?) and `ToHeightValue()`. Then you'll have a strongly-typed, string-less approach. As for the two blocks of code to define the argument and two helper methods: you put those in separate files you'll never have to look at again. And they're easily testable too.

Comment: @CodeCaster I meant the very need to write an Attribute, an Extension Method, an then the Enum. That seems overkill/extra-work to me, specially for this apparently simple task, but maybe it's a matter of getting used to C# programming.

Comment: @heltonbiker: Agreed, you do have to write that additional code. That's what I meant by black-box plumbing code. But you can rest assured, you'll never have to write that piece of code again...

Answer (score 4):

You could create a class:

```
public static class VertebralHeights
{
    public const double C7 = 0.0000000;
    public const double T1 = 0.0391914;
    //...
}
```

Access: `double c7 = VertebralHeights.C7;`

Comment: And you would probably also want public static double FromName(string name) { /* ... */ }

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you are using those mappings. If any lookups by name (`string`) are involved, then `Dictionary` is right choice. But if you only need those numbers to have friendly names, I would go for constants in a class (perhaps static).

It is also easy to enumerate both keys and values in a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();

foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{

}

foreach (var value in dict.Values)
{

}
```

Comment: Could I enumerate them in order? Something like `foreach value in values` or `foreach label in labels`?

Comment: That enumeration wouldn't be in proper order.

Comment: Absolutely, however you would need to handle the ordering. Added sample code to my answer.

Comment: @heltonbiker this works for a dictionary, but not for the class members (unless you use reflection)

Answer (score 2):

To enumerate them, find them by string, and sort them by order, you need to store three pieces of data.  The way you access them changes the way that's best to store them.

1. `List` of tuples containing name and value.

   - This has the primary advantage of ordering.
   - In order to get a specific item by name, you'd need a linq query to retrieve it.
2. `Dictionary` with key of name, and value of tuples containing order and value

   - This has the primary advantage of finding items quickly by name
   - In order to get all the items in a specific order you'd need a linq query to order them.
   - If you just want to loop over all the items without having a specific order, `Dictionary` will allow that.
3. Keep one dictionary and one list of values. - Kind of messy, might be an over-optimization.
4. Make a custom collection that inherits from one of the above implementations and provided the missing functionality hiding the actual implementation.  Linq isn't so slow as to be worrisome with a short list.

Comment: I liked your N° 3 approach. I sort of started to write a class with two private fields: an array of doubles, and an enum of names. But since I am not sure as to how I would actually use this in code, I deferred the implementation of getters and enumerators to when I actually use the code. (I am so unsure that I almost don't even feel able to accept any answer... :o(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple class in a generic collection. Then LINQ makes it easy map the values to one another.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Vertebra {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Vertebra> Vertebrae = new List<Vertebra>() {
                new Vertebra() {name = "C7", height = 0.0000000},
                new Vertebra() {name = "T1", height = 0.0391914}
                //etc
            };

            //find height by name:
            double H = Vertebrae.Single(v => v.name == "C7").height;

            //find name by height:
            string N = Vertebrae.Single(v => v.height == 0.0391914).name;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, for a small collection, list<T> would give better performance! Make it a custom collection to avoid the hassle of calling